# Transcribing javascript to react [Cesium]

Tags: reactjs, cesiumjs

I'm trying to get rid of the timeline in my react website built around Cesium.
The command for that in javascript would be:

```
viewer.timeline.container.style.display = ‘none’
```

How do I translate that in my react return? Right now it looks like this:

```
<Viewer>
<CameraFlyTo
destination={Cartesian3.fromDegrees(26.0514, 44.438, 500)}
duration={5}
/>
<Clock
  startTime={JulianDate.fromIso8601("2020-12-21")}
  currentTime={JulianDate.fromIso8601("2020-12-21")}
  stopTime={JulianDate.fromIso8601("2021-01-21")}
  clockRange={ClockRange.LOOP_STOP} // loop when we hit the end time
  clockStep={ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER}
  multiplier={1} // how much time to advance each tick
  shouldAnimate // Animation on by default
/>
</Viewer>
```

Comment: There's a Viewer constructor parameter to avoid constructing the timeline, which would be better performance than just hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

In resium, the `<Viewer />` component has a read-only boolean prop, `timelime`, which will toggle the visibility of your timeline

If you want to delete the clock in the left corner, you should also write `animation={false}`

This should do the trick:

```
<Viewer timeline={false} animation={false}>
<CameraFlyTo
destination={Cartesian3.fromDegrees(26.0514, 44.438, 500)}
duration={5}
/>
...
```

(Altough it's read-only, I didn't see any warnings from resium about `<Viewer />` being re-rendered)
Hope this works!